# why does my form not work when is being hosted on a server but it works when I run it in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I recently created a website that has a contact us page. When I run the code in Visual Studio, it works. After the user enters the valid input and submits the form in Visual Studio 2022, it works.

When I uploaded my website on a hosting server, I get an error message. I am hosting my page on Hostgator. Can someone please help me fix this problem?

To upload my website from Visual Studio 2022 I published my entire code into a folder. I then uploaded the code to hostgator. This is my website: https://neworiginconstruction.com/Home/Contact

Comment: What is the error?  It could be something is not installed on the server you need that is installed locally.

Comment: There are differences you cannot neglect https://halfblood.pro/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: When I try to submit the contact us form, it gives me an error message. when I run it in my computer it works perfectly. By any change do you what I need to install in my server to make this work.

Comment: I forgot to mention but I am using smtp to email myself once the user has summited the  form.

Comment: does any code behind run? Try a test page. Is there a database connection involved? So, put up a simple test page, when you click a button, put the word "hello" into a text box. Does that code run? And SMTP email? Might not work from the hosting provider - it will depend if emails other then from the hosting provider often don't work. So, put up a test page in your publish, go to that page. If code behind runs, then at least you know IIS and the .net framework you used is supported by the hosting provider. Check their docs for email settings, but sending from other accounts not allowed?

Comment: And is this a asp.net web site, or web site "application"?

Comment: You also forgot to mention the specific error message.  When I fill out the form and submit it (after correcting any input data validation issues), I see the error message `Failure sending mail.` displayed in the UI.  Is this the error message you are referring to or is it something else?

Comment: Did you reconfigure the setup for the outbound email on the HostGator server?  It is almost guaranteed to be different from your local configuration.  https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/email-connection-settings